# How to declare & Initialize a HashMap that Contains A HashSet

Tags: java, hashmap, initialization, declaration, hashset

I am trying to read a Map that contains a string as a key, and a set as a value, how should I go about this? This is what I have got.

```
/**
 * A Class
 */
public class Catalog
{  
   private HashMap <String , Set<String> varieties> aCatalog;

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Catalog
    */
   public Catalog()
   {
      // initialise instance variables
      varieties = new HashSet<>();
      aCatalog = new HashMap<String,varieties>();
   }
}
```

This isn't working, I looked at some similar questions but i couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: *This isn't working*: Can you descripe what it means?

Comment: `aCatalog = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();`

Comment: It will not compile, at the  declaration     

private HashMap <String , Set<String> varieties> aCatalog;

Answer (score 4):

To initialize your map you just need to define the generic types:

```
aCatalog = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

Since java 1.7 you can use the diamond operator:

```
aCatalog = new HashMap<>();
```

To put a value into your map you need to initialize a set:

```
aCatalog.put("theKey", varieties);
```

Comment: I cannot compile as the declaration,     
   `private HashMap <String , Set<String> varieties> aCatalog;`
it says there is an error between the Set<String>*HERE*varieties. the IDE is asking for a ">"

Comment: remove `varieties` from the generic declaration

Comment: That then compiles, but would I then need to add `private HashSet <String> varieties;` as  second declaration

Comment: the changed answer puts the `varieties` to the map

Comment: `private Map<String, Set<String>> aCatalog;` does not compile, "cannot find symbol - Class Map"

Comment: ok, you also need to `import java.util.Map;` (implement against an interface). But you can also replace `Map` by `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
    // declare:
    Map<String, Set<String>> aCatalog;
    // init java 7
    aCatalog = new HashMap<>();
    // insert:
    aCatalog.put("AA", new HashSet<>());
```

or in older versions:

```
    // declare:
    Map<String, Set<String>> aCatalog;
    // init java  
    aCatalog = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    // insert:
    aCatalog.put("AA", new HashSet<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it yourself, there are beautiful [Multimap by Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) which is do that you want.
To initialize you can use builder like this:

```
SetMultimap<String, String> yourMap = MultimapBuilder.hashKeys()
         .linkedHashSetValues().build();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would Love to, unfortuanately we are not allowed such wizardry for my exam!

Answer (score 0):

Okey, you have a problem with the types of your variables, and you are confusing how to initialize your object, here is two way to do it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Catalog {

    //is better to use interface for the type of the variable
    private Map<String, Set<String>> aCatalog;

    // here in your constructor, you just initialize an empty Hash, the most
    // external one
    public Catalog() {
        aCatalog = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        // aCatalog = new HashMap<>(); //this is also valid since 1.7
    }

    //you can also create another constructor, and create the map outside and give it as parameter
    public Catalog(Map<String, Set<String>> catalog) {
        this.aCatalog = catalog;
    }



    public Map<String, Set<String>> getaCatalog() {
        return aCatalog;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //here is an example of creating the map inside the Catalog class
        Catalog catalog1 = new Catalog();

        String key1 = "k1";
        Set<String> valueSet1 = new HashSet<String>();
        valueSet1.add("something 1");
        valueSet1.add("something 2");
        valueSet1.add("something 3");
        String key2 = "k2";
        Set<String> valueSet2 = new HashSet<String>();
        valueSet2.add("other thing1");
        valueSet2.add("other thing2");
        valueSet2.add("other thing3");

        catalog1.getaCatalog().put(key1, valueSet1);
        catalog1.getaCatalog().put(key2, valueSet2);

        //and here is an example of givin as constructor parameter

        Map<String, Set<String>> anotherCatalog = new HashMap<>();
        anotherCatalog.put(key1, valueSet2);
        anotherCatalog.put(key2, valueSet1);

        Catalog catalog2 = new Catalog(anotherCatalog);


    }
}
```

Comment: the declaration of `aCatalog` will not compile due to `varieties` in the generic part

Comment: @Stefan Warminski you are so right thank you very much, I updated the answer, hope that is correct now

Comment: @Damian Lattenero Wouldnt I need to name the set though? as`varieties = new HashSet<String>();` also you missed a ">" `aCatalog = new HashMap<String , Set<String>>();`

Comment: @curiousBadger I updated the answer with two examples so you can test the code! I hope that helps

Comment: @curiousBadger if the answer was useful, don't forget to accept it with the (✓) symbol, you can just accept one answer. Hope that help!